# What is the difference between |+ and |- when creating a configmap from a file in kubernetes yaml definitions?

Tags: kubernetes, yaml, configmap

i've came across 2 types of syntax for creating configmaps from files in kubernetes.

**first one** ;

---

```
apiVersion: v1
data:
  file1.yaml: |+
    parameter1=value1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: my-configmap
```

**second one** ;

```
apiVersion: v1
data:
  file1.yaml: | -
    parameter1=value1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: my-configmap
```

what is the difference between |+ and |- ?

Answer (score 34):

This is the [block chomping indicator](https://yaml-multiline.info/).

Directly  quoting from the link:

> The chomping indicator controls what should happen with newlines at
>   the end of the string. The default, clip, puts a single newline at the
>   end of the string. To remove all newlines, strip them by putting a
>   minus sign (-) after the style indicator. Both clip and strip ignore
>   how many newlines are actually at the end of the block; to keep them
>   all put a plus sign (+) after the style indicator.

This means that for:

```
apiVersion: v1
data:
  file1.yaml: |-
    parameter1=value1


kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: my-configmap
```

file1.yaml will have the value:

```
parameter1=value1
```

For:

```
apiVersion: v1
data:
  file1.yaml: |+
    parameter1=value1


kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: my-configmap
```

file1.yaml will have the value:

```
parameter1=value1 # line break
# line break
# line break
```

Comment: You would do better to refer to the official YAML specification, that way you might have noticed that both of your YAML files are invalid.

Comment: That's correct I just removed the extra spaces causing the error.

Answer (score 2):

These are [block chomping indicators](https://yaml.org/spec/1.2/spec.html#id2794534), they influence how the *trailing* newlines in a literal (`|`) or folded (`>`) block style scalar are handled.

By default, if there is no `+` or `-` after the `|` (or `>`), those trailing newlines are *clipped*, i.e. the scalar will be loaded as a string ending in a **single** newline, independent of whether there are multiple empty lines at the end of the scalar.

If `+` is specified, each newline is *kept*, so the scalar will have one **extra** newline for every empty line before the outdent for the next node (in addition to the one ending the last non-empty line)

If `-` is specified, the scalar is stripped and will not end in a newline, even if there are multiple empty lines at the end of the block style scalar.

Please note that your second example is **invalid**, the [production rules](https://yaml.org/spec/1.2/spec.html#id2795688) indicate that the chomping indicator can only be separated from the `|` by the indentation indicator (i.e. number, if specified) and that no space is allowed between `|` and `-`.